# How do I mask a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a domain (summitesp.info) redirecting (using GoDaddy forwarding) to a subdomain on another site (espanol.summitrdu.com). When I go to a sub-page (i.e. espanol.summitrdu.com/about) I would like for the domain to stay "masked" (i.e. summitesp.info/about). Is there a way to do this easily? I think I would prefer to do it using a .htaccess tweak if possible.

Comment: You can do it directly through Go Daddy: **[Go Daddy Support Doc](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name)**

Comment: As I understand it, the masking through GoDaddy only shows the masked domain (summitesp.info in this case) not any of the URL after the domain name (/about or /contact for example).

Comment: In that case you will want to look into **mod_proxy** which will allow you to make requests from the other website and load pages under the other domain. Make sure you use relative paths for images, scripts, css, etc on the first domain if you want them to be displayed.